# iPhone does not add pkpass Card to Wallet

Tags: ios, iphone, wallet

I have created a iOS Wallet PassCard and signed it (using my MacBook/KeyChain) with a newly created Pass Type ID Certificate.
It works with the iPhone simulator as well as with the Wallet Viewer on the mac.

If I take this .pkpass file and send it by email, the email on the iPhone shows with a wallet attachment file and shows the corresponding wallet icon.

But if I tap on that icon, there is no option to add this card to the wallet. Everything else appear from "saving to file system" to "send by AirDrop" but not Add to Wallet. 
It is the same when sending round as MMS or make a download link on a web server.

What went wrong? Any ideas highly appreciated.